# Storage-In-File Database for C#/.NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, java, database, file, hsqldb

Is there something like HSQLDB (for Java) which can be run in a storage-in-file mode for C#/.NET 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Compact Edition (I guess)

Comment: That sounds great, does SQL Compact supports an user management?

Comment: Nope, encryption and password protection is all you get.
You will need to look at SQL Express for security features.

Comment: Oh, but that's all i need. So i can encrypt and have password protection. That nobody else can look into. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about your requirements, but you could try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: It's working quite nicely for me as unit test DB with NHibernate, a scenario that is fairly common. However that is even an in-memory situation but against file should be working, too.

Comment: Sorry that i didn't mentioned it before: SQLite sadly doesn't support an user management system, it's to easy to look into with another tool.